# Simulate high load for an HTTP API client

Tags: api, http, tcp, client

I am writing a client for an HTTP API which is not yet publicly available.
Based on the specs I got, I have mocked a server which simulates the API, to test how my client reacts.

This server is a very simple Rack application, which currently runs on WEBRick.
The API client interacts with this fake API et performs correctly in the different tests cases.

Hopefully, I will just have to change the hostname in the config file when the API goes live.

However, I know for a fact that the API will be put under heavy load when it goes live. My client will thus most likely have to face :

- HTTP timeouts
- Jitter
- Dropped TCP connections
- 503 Responses
- ...

I know that my client performs well in an ideal scenario, but how can I randomly (or not randomly) introduce these behaviors in my test cases, to verify that the client handles these errors correctly ?

Is there some kind of reverse proxy that can be configured to simulate these errors when serving data from a stable server on a stable network (in my case : local server on localhost) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Net Limiter (http://www.netlimiter.com/) to shape bandwidth.

On the other hand, to make more accurate simulations you need to control both server and client side.

For instance, to simulate timeout condition your mock server can receive request from HTTP API client and then stop, hence triggering timeout on client side.

Other benefits of your own mock/test server is that you can emulate dropped TCP connections (just close newly received client connection), 50X responses, invalid responses, protocol breaking responses and much more.